# Magento Installation Issue on MAC

Tags: php, macos, magento

I am following this [tutorial](http://crosstown.coolestguyplanettech.com/os-x/33-getting-magento-running-on-os-x-lion-107) to install Magento on MAC - OSX Mountain lion.

I am using MAMP and successfully installed mcrypt. In this tutorial it says to move Magento into /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento. But i couldn't locate WebServer folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move your magento files to **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/** .